# ipa icon in itunes

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons, itunes, itunesartwork

hello
i'm building iphone application but when the application apear in itunes it didn't have an icon
this list if icons is 
Icon.png - 57x57 pixels
Icon@2x.png - 114x114 pixels
Icon-72.png - 72x72 pixels
Icon-Small.png - 29x29 pixels
Icon-Small@2x.png - 58x58 pixels
Icon-Small-50.png - 50x50 pixels 
all above icon are listen in the plist file

iTunesArtwork    512x512 pixels

Comment: Where is the iTunesArtwork image?

Comment: Please accept one of the answers as "accepted answers" as it helps out the community of Stackoverflow when you do so, and also adds to your own rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7284-so-how-do-you-deal-itunesartwork.html

It looks like you need to upload your iTunesArtwork image to iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

Download the PDF file from the below link.This will answer all your questions in detail.

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=12&ved=0CB0QFjABOAo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunesconnect.apple.com%2Fdocs%2FiTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf&ei=1oDvTMK0FIqovQOvsrCaDg&usg=AFQjCNHIe5z2hgZca_u0YEjm4U3sU_3b-g&sig2=9BK8FS_s05iGgIVboVhHXQ

Thanks